# How to make Excel show data interactively (view data over "time" step by step)

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen Excel spreadsheets that show data changing over "time"/interactively. For example, as a user hits a button, data will pop up or values will change. The input data can be in other cells in the spreadsheet. For example, lets say I have a table that contains the the number of users connected to a website for each hour of the day. I can show a static table that contains all of the data, but I've seen spreadsheets where each time a user clicks a button, it shows a new hour and the associated number of users - so it is showing the interim data for each button click until the last hour at which point the full data is visible.

Does anyone know how this is done, and if this is standard Excel functionality, or requires macros?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic way to achieve this - from here, you can grow and expand your knowledge with experimentation.

Imagine you have your table of Users by Hour data (B1:Y10), with a different hour in each column. For complexity, let's say that each row is a count by region, with the final row being a Total column.

For your interactive chart, you'd just want to show a single hour (column) at a time, that the user can change. So we create a reference column in col A. This would go in A2 (A1 being the header)

```
=index(B2:Y10,A15)
```

What goes in A15? That's going to be the number of columns over you want to look at - which will be controlled by the user!

Go to your Developer tab on the Ribbon (if you don't have one, go to File>Options>Customize Ribbon and check Developer). From this tab, select the Spin Button from the Form Control section (it looks like up and down arrows) and draw one.

Right click, select Format Control. Under the Control tab, change Cell link to A15. Set the Max Value to 24 (24hr day).

Now, when you click the arrow, the number will increment by one, and cause your formula to look at a different column. Create your chart based on this dynamic column, and you're done!

Like I said, this is a basic framework for the general concept. There's quite a bit more you can do on this subject! I highly recommend experimenting with it! Good luck :)

Comment: I tried this and can see how this can be used as a basic building block to show data from existing cells controlled by a button. Leaving this unanswered for the moment to see if there is a different approach. If not, then will select as the answer.